# remove the style from within the table tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a complete html page where i need to remove the `<style>` tags within the html table tags, how can i do in jquery,

i am trying like this jquery

```
$("#container").find("table > style").removeattr("style");
```

But that does not seems to remove the code from it. well that is not the only table in the page, the page contains 10's of tables so how can i moniter how to remove the complete style from this page.

even i tried it like this:

```
$("#container").find("table").find("style").removeattr("style");
```

does not to work

Comment: Do you really have `style` **elements** with `style` **attributes** in your code? I.e. `<style style="..." />`? Because that's what you are trying to find / do. `style` elements are actually invalid outside of `<head>`.

Comment: Can you show a sample of HTML code you have?

Comment: @FelixKling: `style` elements can be placed outside of `head`. http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Comment: @Ginden: Ah. Must be some new HTML5 voodoo ;)

Comment: It's old (2011) but it isn't widely adopted as it is almost useless except for 3rd party ads or similar objects m

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the selector... use this:

```
$("#container").find("table[style]").removeAttr("style");
```

That will remove the style attribute from all tables with a style attribute. Also, `.removeattr` is supposed to be `.removeAttr`.

If you're trying to remove style *tags* and not *attributes*, it would be

```
$("#container table").find("style").remove();
```

HTH,
-Ted

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `<style>` tag inside the `<table>` you need to do like:

`$('#container table > style').remove();`

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/a4b5gfg5/

In case you need to clear `style` attribute:

`$('selector').attr('style', null);`